# Install Erlang Cassandra Cqerl

Tags: cassandra, erlang, nitrogen

I have a Cassandra cluster that I need to connect with Nitrogen? I installed Cqerl as instructed yet cannot make the connection. I do not think i installed the dependency correctly. When trying to make the connection from the console i get "undefined function cqerl".

I have run the "make test" and have got connect "failed".

Could someone guide me on installing the dependency and making the connection.

Comment: Could you explain a bit how you installed it? Do you use rebar, erlang.mk or simple Makefiles?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a standard Nitrogen installation, then adding the following line to your rebar.config in the "deps" section should properly bring in the cqerl dependency:

`{cqerl, "", {git, "git://github.com/matehat/cqerl", {branch, master}}},`

This should make the whole deps section of your rebar.config look something like this:

```
{deps, [
    {cowboy,        ".*",   {git, "git://github.com/ninenines/cowboy",      {tag, "1.0.1"}}},

    %% CQERL Dependency
    {cqerl,         ".*",   {git, "git://github.com/matehat/cqerl",         {branch, master}}},


    %% Uncomment the following lines and comment the bottom lines with specific
    %% tags to always pull the latest versions
    {simple_bridge, ".*",   {git, "git://github.com/nitrogen/simple_bridge",{branch, master}}},
    {nprocreg,      ".*",   {git, "git://github.com/nitrogen/nprocreg",     {branch, master}}},
    {nitrogen_core, ".*",   {git, "git://github.com/nitrogen/nitrogen_core",{branch, master}}},
    {sync,          ".*",   {git, "git://github.com/rustyio/sync",          {branch, master}}}
]}.
```

I have no experience with cassandra or cqerl, so I can't give any advice on how to properly use cqerl, but that should get it installed as a dependency properly.  If there are configs that need to be used, make sure to add them to your Nitrogen installation's `etc` directory.